# Приложение для построения графиков

Tags: поиск-программ, визуализация, графики

Подскажите простое приложение для построения графиков из произвольных данных. То бишь у меня есть некоторый файл с массивом данных (каждый элемент в массиве - это набор параметров в определенный момент времени) в специфическом формате (который можно перегнать в `json`, `xml` и любой другой формат) из которого мне нужно построить график лишь по определенному параметру или по нескольким параметрам. Очень хотелось бы иметь приложение наподобие `graphviz`

UDP "наподобие `graphviz`" - имеется ввиду консольная тула позволяющая формировать графики в `svg`, `png` и других форматах, позволяющая просто автоматизировать построение графиков

Comment: майкрософт эксель.

Comment: @Эникейщик это уж точно ни чем не похожа на `graphviz`, только под `windows`, к тому же как автоматизировать? Одназначно нет

Comment: про автоматизировать в вопросе ни слова. А что такое graphviz известно далеко не всем.

Comment: @Эникейщик автоматизация мне казалась настолько очевидной, что я даже не подумал это включать в вопрос. Дополню вопрос

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает сама graphviz?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov насколько мне известно (а я знаком с `graphviz` поверхностно) в ней нельзя визуализировать графики - тула все таки для графов, а это разные вещи

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/birt/